# Can I optimize Explorer.exe for a slow drive?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, network-drive

Is it possible to give a hint to Explorer.exe that it's dealing with slow drive, for example, something like a network share? Explorer should go easy with it, i.e. not constantly looking up `desktop.ini` attributes.

Comment: Explorer does not use `Desktop.ini` unless the folder has the "read-only" and/or "system" flags, specifically for [network performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/30/55100.aspx) reasons. (Not sure about equivalent flags for file metadata lookup, though.)

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing you can do to speed up Explorer is to [disable thumnails](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-turn-off-image-preview-thumbnail-and-disable-windows-picture-and-fax-viewer-in-windows-xp/). This limits any "automatic" access to polling the filesystem.

To do so, run `regsvr32 /u shimgvw.dll` and `regsvr32 /u shmedia.dll` in a command prompt (Start->All Programs->Accessories).

In addition, you might also want to increase your filesystem RAM cache so that XP doesn't have to keep calling the filesystem for files. You can do with with the SysInternals utility [CacheSet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897561.aspx).

And if you're paranoid, please back up. Windows XP is going the way of the dinosaur and behaves kind of like one.

Comment: FWIW, Explorer doesn't poll the filesystem; it uses the change notification API.

Comment: No matter what, it will eventually cause a filesysyem read though…

Answer (score 0):

Limiting 3rd party shell extensions and real time anti malware will also go a long way toward increasing Explorer's performance.